props.OnNewTicketCreation is not a function
I'm having a problem passing a prop function. I'm following a tutorial and can't seem to identify the issue with my prop, solutions to questions asked don't relate to my challenge which is rather simple
The ticket control is the class based component holding state. The function of interest is handleAddingNewTicketToList. Pasted below
import React from 'react';
import NewTicketForm from './NewTicketForm';
import TicketList from './TicketList';
import TicketDetail from './TicketDetail';

class TicketControl extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            formVisibleOnPage: false,
            mainTicketList: [],
            slectedTicket: null,
        };
    }

    // handleClick = () => {
    //     this.setState(prevState => ({  // This function uses parentheses () around the object returned by the arrow function. This syntax indicates an implicit return, meaning that the object inside the parentheses is the return value of the arrow function.
    //         formVisibleOnPage: !prevState.formVisibleOnPage
    //     }))
    // }

    handleClick = () => {
        if (this.state.selectedTicket != null) {
            this.setState({
                formVisibleOnPage: false,
                selectedTicket: null,
            });
        } else {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                formVisibleOnPage: !prevState.formVisibleOnPage,
            }));
        }
    }

    handleAddingNewTicketToList = (newTicket) => {
        const newMainTicketList = this.state.mainTicketList.concat(newTicket); // .concat creates a duplicate, .push doesnt
        this.setState({
            mainTicketList: newMainTicketList,
            formVisibleOnPage: false,
        });
    }

    handleChangingSelectedTicket = (id) => {
        const selectedTicket = this.state.mainTicketList.filter(ticket => ticket.id === id)[0];
        this.setState({ selectedTicket: selectedTicket })
    }

    handleDeletingTicket = (id) => {
        const newMainTicketList = this.state.mainTicketList.filter(ticket => ticket.id !== id);
        this.setState({
            mainTicketList: newMainTicketList,
            selectedTicket: null
        });
    }

    render() {
        let currentVisibleState = null;
        let buttonText = null;

        if (this.state.selectedTicket != null) {
            currentVisibleState = <TicketDetail ticket={this.state.selectedTicket} onClickingDelete = {this.handleDeletingTicket}/>
            buttonText = "Return to Ticket List"
        }
        else if (this.state.formVisibleOnPage) {
            currentVisibleState = <NewTicketForm
                onNewTicketCreation={this.handleAddingNewTicketToList}
            />
            buttonText = "Return to Ticket List";
        }
        else {
            currentVisibleState = <TicketList ticketList={this.state.mainTicketList} onTicketSelection={this.handleChangingSelectedTicket} />
            buttonText = "Add Ticket"
        }

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {currentVisibleState}
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{buttonText}</button>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }

}

export default TicketControl;

The NewticketForm handles adding a new ticket and holds a form.
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { v4 } from "uuid";
import ReusableForm from "./ReusableForm";

function NewTicketForm(props) {


    function handleNewTicketFormSubmission(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        props.OnNewTicketCreation({
            names: event.target.names.value,
            location: event.target.location.value,
            issue: event.target.issue.value,
            id: v4(),
            // numberOfStudents: parseInt(event.target.numberOfStudents.value) // How to parse numeric data
        });

    }


    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <React.Fragment>
                <ReusableForm
                    formSubmissionHandler={handleNewTicketFormSubmission}
                    buttonText="Help!" />
            </React.Fragment>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

NewTicketForm.propTypes = {
    OnNewTicketCreation: PropTypes.func,
    // func1: PropTypes.func,
}

export default NewTicketForm;

The error arises on line 11 when running props.OnNewTicketCreation({. I've used breakpoints and can return the function from console.

Looks like it's a typo.
In your NewTicketForm component, you're trying to call props.OnNewTicketCreation with a capital "O", but in your TicketControl component, you're passing the prop as onNewTicketCreation with a lowercase "o".
props.onNewTicketCreation({
    names: event.target.names.value,
    location: event.target.location.value,
    issue: event.target.issue.value,
    id: v4(),
});


I feel really dumb about the simplest problem in the book. But thank for spotting that one.
